# Tag file encoding with Jetty

Tags: java, encoding, jetty, jsp-tags

When I put non ascii letters in a .tag file, those letters are not correctly encoded.

My application runs on jetty 8.1.4.

If a .tag file contains `é`, it will appears in the resulting HTML page as `Ã©`.
When I put the same letter in a JSP file, it gets correctly displayed.
If I pass the same character as a parameter to the tag, it gets correctly displayed.

The encoding of the files is UTF-8. The result page is also encoded in UTF-8.
I've the same problem when running the application from Eclipse on ubuntu, or when deploying the tag in a jar on a debian server.

I checked the java file generated by jetty for the tag, and the `é` get transformed into :

```
out.write('Ã');
out.write('©');
```

So the encoding is wrong when the tag is precompiled into a java class.

Can I control the encoding at this step, or specify the encoding in the .tag file ?

---

Here are some more details.

The tag file contains only one character : `é`. It is encoded as `C3 A9` when viewed in hex (correct UTF-8 encoding).
The java file is the following :

```
package org.apache.jsp.tag.web.tagLink.layout;

import javax.servlet.*; import javax.servlet.http.*; import javax.servlet.jsp.*;

public final class test_tag
    extends javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.SimpleTagSupport
    implements org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspSourceDependent {


  private static final JspFactory _jspxFactory = JspFactory.getDefaultFactory();

  private static java.util.Vector _jspx_dependants;

  private JspContext jspContext;   private java.io.Writer _jspx_sout;  private org.glassfish.jsp.api.ResourceInjector _jspx_resourceInjector;

  public void setJspContext(JspContext ctx) {
    super.setJspContext(ctx);
    java.util.ArrayList _jspx_nested = null;
    java.util.ArrayList _jspx_at_begin = null;
    java.util.ArrayList _jspx_at_end = null;
    this.jspContext = new org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspContextWrapper(ctx, _jspx_nested,
_jspx_at_begin, _jspx_at_end, null);   }

  public JspContext getJspContext() {
    return this.jspContext;   }

  public Object getDependants() {
    return _jspx_dependants;   }

  public void doTag() throws JspException, java.io.IOException {
    PageContext _jspx_page_context = (PageContext)jspContext;
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) _jspx_page_context.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) _jspx_page_context.getResponse();
    HttpSession session = _jspx_page_context.getSession();
    ServletContext application = _jspx_page_context.getServletContext();
    ServletConfig config = _jspx_page_context.getServletConfig();
    JspWriter out = jspContext.getOut();

    try {
      out.write('Ã');
      out.write('©');
    } catch( Throwable t ) {
      if( t instanceof SkipPageException )
          throw (SkipPageException) t;
      if( t instanceof java.io.IOException )
          throw (java.io.IOException) t;
      if( t instanceof IllegalStateException )
          throw (IllegalStateException) t;
      if( t instanceof JspException )
          throw (JspException) t;
      throw new JspException(t);
    } finally {
      ((org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspContextWrapper) jspContext).syncEndTagFile();
    }   } }
```

When looking the parameters of the two `out.write` calls, they are `C3 83` and `C2 A9`. The rest is just plain ASCII.

I've created a JSP page which only includes the test tag, an when viewed from the browser, I receive : `C3 83 C2 A9`. Here is the picture taken with Fiddler2, the browser is IE8 :

[image: data received from the jetty server].

If I put the `é` character directly in the JSP page, it is encoded as `C3 A9` in the java generated file, and in the message received on the browser.

Comment: What *exactly* does the response look like, including headers and the *binary data*. (Use Wireshark to capture a small sample response - just a single word, ideally - and include it in your question.)

Comment: In tag file, the character is "C3 A9". In the java file, the character are "C3 83" and "C2 A9". Both the .tag and the java file should be UTF-8 encoded

Comment: I asked what the response to the browser looked like. That's the important part, in terms of results. Do you know that the generated java file should *definitely* be in UTF-8? Is that a configuration option somewhere?

Comment: I see your point. It's just that it is more difficult to isolate a simple test including the browser. I will try to do that tomorrow.

Comment: Knowing about the .java files is important too, of course. It would be great if you could provide a sample (really simple) .tag file, a sample of the Java it creates, and a sample of the response that generates... ideally in each case with both the text and a snippet of the binary data (viewed with hexdump or whatever). I should confess now that I've never used Jetty - but I've tracked down lots of encoding issues before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer was given by Jan.

Adding the following line in the tag file will correct the issue :

```
<%@tag pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use direct UTF-8 bytes in your JSP if you are going to be producing HTML.

A quick check of my favorite UTF-8 utility shows that your character is :

http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=C3+A9&mode=bytes

So, use one of the following instead.

- `&#233;` (numeric UTF-8 sequence, best supported in most browsers)
- `&#x00E9;`  (hex UTF-8 sequence, works in majority of browsers)

Here's an example in HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    Example (numeric UTF-8): &#233; <br/>
    Example (hex UTF-8); &#x00E9; <br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I'm french, and we use accentuated letters, which are not in the ascii table. It would be a pain to replace them by a code point or a html entity in all the jsp file. Fortunately the bug doesn't appear for .jsp files, so I can use your solution as a temporary workaround in .tag files.

Comment: To be clear, does your .tag file contain the following directive: <%@tag pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> ?

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. Adding the pageEncoding in the tag file works perfectly. If you modify your response with this information, I would be happy to accept it. Thanks a lot.